# Dynamic UIButton positioning?

Tags: ios, dynamic, uibutton, positioning

I have rewards that a user can get in my game. Now they only show if they unlock them. There are 4 different rewards they can get. Now they may have 1 reward unlocked or 2 or 3 or 4. However I want the images to be positioned dynamically so it looks like the image below. In the image below, each line should look the way it is with the number of rewards unlocked.
[image]

Now, how would I go upon doing this? (Note: The images are not changing on the Y axis, they will just be dynamically positioned on the X axis, so don't be fooled by the image)

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, you have managed to thoroughly confuse me...  Can you show an example with 1, 2, 3, and 4 rewards unlocked?  I'm not sure what you mean when you say "The images are not changing on the Y axis, they will just be dynamically positioned on the X axis, so don't be fooled by the image" or "each line should look the way it is with the number of rewards unlocked."....

Comment: Hmmm...  Maybe you mean that you can have from one to four boxes on each line?  And the pyramid is just a coincidence in this case?

Comment: There is only 1 line, the placement of one or all the buttons will be the same value on the Y axis. Now if it is 1 reward, it should look like the first line of the image, if it is 2, it should look like the second line of the image, etc... The center of the image in this question would represent the middle of the device.

Comment: Pretty much I just want to space out the reward images equally on the X axis depending on the number of reward images there are which can range from 1 to 4 in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a custom `UIView` subclass that does this so that you can use it anywhere that a view can be used.

**Usage**:

```
MyFlexibleSpacedButtons *myButtons = [[MyFlexibleSpacedButtons alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 250, 60)];
[myButtons setButtonAtIndex:2 hidden:NO];
[myButtons setButtonAtIndex:0 hidden:NO];
[self.view addSubview:myButtons];
```

Here is the example class:

**MyFlexibleSpacedButtons.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyFlexibleSpacedButtons : UIView

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *allButtons;

- (void)setButtonAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index hidden:(BOOL)hidden;

@end
```

**MyFlexibleSpacedButtons.m**:

```
#import "MyFlexibleSpacedButtons.h"

const NSUInteger    maxButtons          = 9;
const NSUInteger    buttonsPerRow       = 3; // This can not be 0.
const CGFloat       buttonHeight        = 50;
const CGFloat       buttonWidth         = 50;
const CGFloat       spaceBetweenButtons = 10.0;

@interface MyFlexibleSpacedButtons ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSArray        *allButtons;
@end

@implementation MyFlexibleSpacedButtons

@synthesize allButtons;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSUInteger numberOfRows = ceil((double)maxButtons / (double)buttonsPerRow);
    CGFloat    minHeight    = buttonHeight * numberOfRows + spaceBetweenButtons * (numberOfRows - 1);
    if (frame.size.height < minHeight)
    {
        frame.size.height = minHeight;
    }

    CGFloat minWidth = buttonWidth * maxButtons + spaceBetweenButtons * (maxButtons-1);
    if (frame.size.width < minWidth)
    {
        frame.size.width = minWidth;
    }

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Defaults
        // Uncomment the following line if needed for debugging:
        // self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        // Create the buttons and add them to the array.  Default to hidden buttons
        self.allButtons = [NSArray new];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxButtons; i++)
        {
            UIButton *button   = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.hidden      = YES;
            [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self addSubview:button];
            self.allButtons = [self.allButtons arrayByAddingObject:button];
        }

        [self setButtonFrames];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    allButtons = nil;
}

- (void)setButtonFrames
{
    CGFloat viewHeight                  = self.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat viewWidth                   = self.bounds.size.width;

    NSUInteger  buttonCount             = [self visibleButtonsCount];
    NSUInteger  numberOfRows            = ceil((double)maxButtons / (double)buttonsPerRow);
    CGFloat     buttonY                 = (viewHeight - buttonHeight * numberOfRows - spaceBetweenButtons * (numberOfRows - 1)) / 2;
    CGFloat     buttonGroupTotalWidth   = buttonCount * buttonWidth + (buttonCount - 1) * spaceBetweenButtons;
    CGFloat     buttonGroupStartingX    = (viewWidth - buttonGroupTotalWidth) / 2;

    // Set frames of buttons
    NSUInteger  visibleButtonIndex      = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxButtons; i++)
    {
        UIButton *button    = [self.allButtons objectAtIndex:i];

        if (!button.hidden)
        {
            CGFloat buttonX     = buttonGroupStartingX + visibleButtonIndex % buttonsPerRow * (buttonWidth + spaceBetweenButtons);
            button.frame        = CGRectMake(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
            visibleButtonIndex++;

            if (visibleButtonIndex % buttonsPerRow == 0)
            {
                buttonY = buttonY + buttonHeight + spaceBetweenButtons;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)setButtonAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index hidden:(BOOL)hidden
{
    if (index > maxButtons - 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    UIButton *button    = [self.allButtons objectAtIndex:index];
    button.hidden       = hidden;

    [self setButtonFrames];
}

- (NSUInteger)visibleButtonsCount
{
    NSUInteger buttonCount = 0;

    for (UIButton *button in self.allButtons)
    {
        if (!button.hidden)
        {
            buttonCount++;
        }
    }
    return buttonCount;
}

@end
```

Comment: This looks amazing and exactly what I want however I have one issue with this. You create 4 buttons manually but I only want to create it if a BOOL in NSUserDefaults is YES. Each button's key is "Button1", "Button2", etc... So instead of creating them all manually, how would I create the buttons only if the bool returns YES for each button's key?

Comment: I simplified this a little by creating them all in the beginning so that I can safely assume that they are all there.  Then I just hide the ones that I don't need.  To change the number of visible buttons, I just change the `visibleButtons` property to the number that I want to show!

Comment: Ah ok I see but how would I show or hide specific buttons depending on their value from user defaults? Thats why I only wanted to show the buttons depending on the user defaults bool.

Comment: I changed the class so that they can be turned on and off individually.

Comment: Thanks and just so I understand correctly lets say button 1 and button 4 are the only buttons that are showing. They won't have a space of 40.0 according to your code but instead 10.0 like it should right? (Just to explain, button 4 would go into button 2's typical spot if button 2 isn't showing right?)

Comment: Correct, and it doesn't matter which order that you set them to visible.  Button 2 will always show before button 4.

Comment: Excellent, I will implement this tomorrow and will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Another quick question, if I have more than 4 buttons that I want to use with your code, what values in the class do I have to change in order for it to work. I think it would work better with a #define for number of buttons but I just don't want to break the code you have here!

Comment: Okay, I added that.  This should be enough to get you going on your own...  :)

Comment: I hate to keep nagging, but how would I also add the ability to have 'rows' like a spacing of 10 in between each row and say have a certain amount of buttons in each row (like say there are 6 buttons showing, buttons with index 0,1,2 will be in the first row and buttons with index 3,4,5 will be in the second)? I will give you a bounty for this!

Comment: The easiest way would be to just create two of these, each with three buttons, and just stack them on top of each other.  Then in the code that turns the buttons on and off, just pick the right one!  If it were me though, I would try to keep it generic and not have different versions just for varying numbers of rows.

Comment: Yea I agree, I would want to use only one of this instead of two but I am just not sure how I would go upon making the actual second row in code.

Comment: What if indexes 1, 4, and 5 are visible?  Would all three be in the top row or one in the top row and two in the bottom row?

Comment: In that case there would only be 1 row. There should be a constant for the number of button in each row along with a constant for the number of rows. That way it is easy to customize. :) Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Actually, you should just need the number of buttons per row.  The number of rows is determined by the number of total buttons and the number of buttons per row.  :)

Comment: But how would I implement this properly? I am just not understanding the logistics of it.

Comment: I don't have time to properly implement this tonight, and have a busy day tomorrow so I'm not sure when I will be able to get it.  I still recommend just having one view for each row.  If you need to be able to move them together, you can always create a view of your own which is big enough to hold all of them and just move it.

Comment: Are you free tonight? Would you be able to show me how to implement the two rows, I am having difficultly using 2 different objects.

Comment: Also there appears to be a leak in this line: self.allButtons = [NSArray new];

Comment: I wrote this using ARC so there is no leak.  If you aren't using ARC then a fair amount should change....

Comment: Oh I just put in a autorelease and it seemed to fix it. I don't see any other leaks so its pretty good. However after even more testing, using 2 allocations of this does not work. Would you just be able to put together some pseudo code for the 2 rows? I will give you a bounty!!! :)

Comment: Well, I actually started this, but the question is what should it look like if you have, say 3 buttons per row, and you have 8 visible?  Obviously, two of the rows would be full (the top two, or the bottom two?) and then the third row would only have two buttons.  Should they be centered or left justified along with the rest of the buttons?

Comment: The rows would be aligned vertically so the rows would only be changed on the Y axis. In the case of where the number of buttons is indivisible by three, the last row will just be how ever many buttons are left so in that case of 8 buttons, that last row would have 2 buttons.

Comment: And those last two buttons are left aligned, and not centered like in your picture above?  (That was my main question.)

Comment: Oh, and the row with two buttons should be at the top or bottom?

Comment: Wow that is really fantastic! I will give you 50 reputation points shortly :P. Also one last question how would I change the spacing in between each row?

Comment: Also when I say spacing in between in each row, I mean independently from the spacing for the width in between each button.

Comment: This is set in the `setButtonFrames` method.  On both lines that are setting `buttonY`, change `spaceBetweenButtons` to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and more flexible way would be to use an UITableView and a custom cell with a method: `- (void)NumberOfButtonsInCell:(NSUInteger)buttons;`

so when called in the tableView data source

you just set the number of buttons accordingly as

```
- (void)numberOfButtonsInCell:(NSUInteger)buttons {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i<buttons;i++) {
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.widht/buttons)*i, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];

  button.tag = i;

  [self addSubview:button];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  }
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
   UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

   [self.delegate userDidSelectButtonAtIndex:(button.tag)];
   //so your table view resolves the row with [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];



}
```

That way you can set a method, for    `[cell configureButtonAtIndex:index];`

You could easily change all the behavior, the looks, and even the design, with a few lines of code.

Comment: I understand, however I'm asking specifically on how to achieve the design (positioning) of the buttons depending on how many there are.

Comment: Just use [cell numberOfButtonsInCell:i]; which uses int i = i + 1; int count += i; (at least in the example image you use) and set i as indexPath.row in that geometric structure you will always be having empty buttons depending on the number of buttons, you will have to make the bottom row bigger (adding more buttons) if you want to avoid  having empty buttons so if count >= totalOfButtonYouNeed (you add the buttons to the prior cell) (sorry for the mess, the cell its configured in the data source methods and the logics, could be done prior in viewDidLoad so you don't need to reload the table)